How to get a windows keyboard layout "description"
I am currently making a Windows app with Python, and it needs to get all installed system layouts:

I've already got the basic thing working using the Win32 APIs GetKeyboardLayoutList and GetLocaleInfoW:

Though I'm still missing the "description" (I'm not sure what else to call it), ie the "Microsoft IME" or "German" in the first screenshot above.
The function I use to get all layouts:
import ctypes

user32 = ctypes.windll.user32

def get_all_layouts() -> None:
    n_layouts = user32.GetKeyboardLayoutList(0, None)
    buffer = (ctypes.c_ulong * n_layouts)()
    user32.GetKeyboardLayoutList(n_layouts, ctypes.byref(buffer))
    layouts = []

    for layout in buffer:
        layout_id = layout & 0xFFFF
        layout_name = get_layout_name(layout_id)
        layout_description = get_layout_description(layout_id)

        if layout_name:
            layouts.append({
                'name': layout_name,
                'description': layout_description
            })
            continue

        print('Failed to get layout name')

    return layouts

And the get_layout_name function from above:
import ctypes

user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
LOCALE_SLANGUAGE = 0x00000002

def get_layout_name(layout: int) -> str:
    name = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(256)

    if ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLocaleInfoW(layout, LOCALE_SLANGUAGE, name, 256):
        return name.value

    return ''

The get_layout_description is currently empty.
I have tried looking through the other "Locale Information Constants" found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/locale-information-constants
I tried functions like GetKeyNameTextW, GetKeyboardLayoutNameW, and even LoadKeyboardLayoutW or ActivateKeyboardLayout with GetKeyboardLayout, and got either the wrong things, or just nothing.

I can find it under Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CTF\TIP\{ID}\LanguageProfile\0x00000411\{ID} Description value name. You may try ITfInputProcessorProfiles::GetLanguageProfileDescription.

There are two types of input methods in Windows - keyboard layouts and IME (Input method editor) layouts or TSF Profiles. AFAIK GetKeyboardLayoutList API returns only keyboard layouts.



First line in language bar entry is Language Name under which keyboard layout is installed. You can just take low word of KLID or HKL to get input language ID and call GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_SLOCALIZEDDISPLAYNAME). GetKeyboardLayoutName API returns KLID.
Second line in language bar entry is Keyboard Layout name. You have to load layout name from Layout Display Name or Layout Text key under HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts\<KLID> registry key. See Create Resources for Keyboard Layout Strings and WinForms code that doing that here.

Is case of TSF HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CTF\TIP\<CLASSID>\LanguageProfile\<LANGID>\<PROFILEID> registry key should be used. For first line just use LANGID in GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_SLOCALIZEDDISPLAYNAME) call. For second line you have
to load IME string name - "Microsoft IME" string from Description or Display Description values. Also, you can try to make use of ITfInputProcessorProfiles::GetLanguageProfileDescription() that is doing that under the hood. But I find using this API difficult in practice.
Here is list of keyboard layouts generated from live Windows system and here is tool that I wrote to generate these tables. I think you can reuse   parts of this code (convert it to python yourself):
constexpr wchar_t KeyboardLayoutsRegistryPath[] = L"SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Keyboard Layouts";

std::wstring GetKeyboardLayoutDisplayName(_In_ LPCWSTR pwszKLID)
{
    // http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2006/05/06/591174.html
    typedef HRESULT(WINAPI* SHLoadIndirectStringFunc)(PCWSTR pszSource, PWSTR pszOutBuf, UINT cchOutBuf, void** ppvReserved);
    static SHLoadIndirectStringFunc SHLoadIndirectString = reinterpret_cast<SHLoadIndirectStringFunc>(::GetProcAddress(::LoadLibraryA("shlwapi.dll"), "SHLoadIndirectString"));

    HKEY key;
    CHECK_EQ(::RegOpenKeyW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, KeyboardLayoutsRegistryPath, &key), ERROR_SUCCESS);

    WCHAR layoutDisplayName[MAX_PATH] = {};
    DWORD layoutDispalyNameSize = static_cast<DWORD>(std::size(layoutDisplayName));

    LSTATUS errorCode = ::RegGetValueW(key, pwszKLID, L"Layout Display Name", RRF_RT_REG_SZ, nullptr, layoutDisplayName, &layoutDispalyNameSize);
    if (errorCode == ERROR_SUCCESS && SHLoadIndirectString)
    {
        // Convert string like "@%SystemRoot%\system32\input.dll,-5000" to localized "US" string
        CHECK_EQ(SHLoadIndirectString(layoutDisplayName, layoutDisplayName, MAX_PATH, nullptr), S_OK);
    }
    else
    {
        // Fallback to unlocalized layout name
        CHECK_EQ(::RegGetValueW(key, pwszKLID, L"Layout Text", RRF_RT_REG_SZ, nullptr, layoutDisplayName, &layoutDispalyNameSize), ERROR_SUCCESS);
    }

    if (errorCode == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        DCHECK(wcslen(layoutDisplayName) != 0);
    }

    CHECK_EQ(::RegCloseKey(key), ERROR_SUCCESS);

    return layoutDisplayName;
}

constexpr wchar_t TSFProfilesRegistryPath[] = L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\CTF\\TIP";

// HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CTF\TIP\{CLSID}\LanguageProfile\[langid]\{guidProfile}
std::wstring GetTSFProfileRegistryPath(const LCID& langId, const CLSID& clsId, const GUID& profileGuid)
{
    wchar_t* clsIdStr;
    CHECK_EQ(::StringFromCLSID(clsId, &clsIdStr), S_OK);

    wchar_t guidStr[MAX_PATH] = {};
    CHECK(::StringFromGUID2(profileGuid, (LPOLESTR)&guidStr, static_cast<int>(std::size(guidStr))) > 0);

    wchar_t path[MAX_PATH] = {};
    swprintf_s(path, std::size(path), L"%s\\%s\\LanguageProfile\\0x%08x\\%s", TSFProfilesRegistryPath, clsIdStr, langId, guidStr);

    ::CoTaskMemFree(clsIdStr);

    return path;
}

std::wstring GetTSFProfileDisplayName(const LCID& langId, const CLSID& clsId, const GUID& profileGuid)
{
    typedef HRESULT(WINAPI* SHLoadIndirectStringFunc)(PCWSTR pszSource, PWSTR pszOutBuf, UINT cchOutBuf, void** ppvReserved);
    static SHLoadIndirectStringFunc SHLoadIndirectString = reinterpret_cast<SHLoadIndirectStringFunc>(::GetProcAddress(::LoadLibraryA("shlwapi.dll"), "SHLoadIndirectString"));

    std::wstring registryPath = GetTSFProfileRegistryPath(langId, clsId, profileGuid);

    HKEY key;
    CHECK_EQ(::RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, registryPath.c_str(), 0, KEY_READ, &key), ERROR_SUCCESS);

    WCHAR layoutDisplayName[MAX_PATH] = {};
    DWORD layoutDispalyNameSize = static_cast<DWORD>(std::size(layoutDisplayName));

    LSTATUS errorCode = ::RegGetValueW(key, nullptr, L"Display Description", RRF_RT_REG_SZ, nullptr, layoutDisplayName, &layoutDispalyNameSize);
    if (errorCode == ERROR_SUCCESS && SHLoadIndirectString)
    {
        // Convert string like "@%SystemRoot%\system32\input.dll,-5000" to localized string
        CHECK_EQ(SHLoadIndirectString(layoutDisplayName, layoutDisplayName, MAX_PATH, nullptr), S_OK);
    }
    else
    {
        // Fallback to unlocalized profile name
        errorCode = ::RegGetValueW(key, nullptr, L"Description", RRF_RT_REG_SZ, nullptr, layoutDisplayName, &layoutDispalyNameSize);
    }

    if (errorCode == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        DCHECK(wcslen(layoutDisplayName) != 0);
    }

    CHECK_EQ(::RegCloseKey(key), ERROR_SUCCESS);

    return layoutDisplayName;
}

std::wstring GetLocaleName(LANGID lang)
{
    wchar_t localeName[MAX_PATH] = {};
    CHECK(::LCIDToLocaleName(lang, localeName, (int)std::size(localeName), 0) > 0);

    return localeName;
}

std::wstring GetLocaleDisplayName(const std::wstring& localeName)
{
    static std::map<std::wstring, std::wstring> cache;
    if (cache.find(localeName) != cache.end())
    {
        return cache[localeName];
    }

    wchar_t string[MAX_PATH] = {};
    CHECK(::GetLocaleInfoEx(localeName.c_str(), LOCALE_SLOCALIZEDDISPLAYNAME, string, (int)std::size(string)) > 0);

    cache[localeName] = string;

    return string;
}

std::wstring GetLanguageDisplayName(LANGID lang)
{
    return GetLocaleDisplayName(GetLocaleName(lang));
}

